# Alfresco Object is not available in extension module in alfresco share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to override the javascript controller node-header.js of components\node-details with the extension module of alfresco share

This is my node-header.get.js

```
<import resource="classpath:/alfresco/templates/org/alfresco/import/alfresco-util.js">
for (var i=0; i<model.widgets.length; i++)
{
    if (model.widgets[i].id == "NodeHeader")
    { 
        if(model.widgets[i].options.nodeRef!=null)
        {
            var jsNode = new Alfresco.util.Node(model.widgets[i].options.nodeRef);
            if(jsNode.hasAspect("custom:intranetFile")){
                model.widgets[i].options.showFavourite = false; 
                model.widgets[i].options.showLikes = false;      
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

> Error Message: 05270002 Failed to execute script
>   'classpath*:webscripts/custom/nodeheader/hidelikesync/node-header.get.js':
>   05270001 ReferenceError: "Alfresco" is not defined.
>   (jar:file:/C:/Alfresco/Alfresco42/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/lib/customshare.jar!/webscripts/custom/nodeheader/hidelikesync/node-header.get.js#1555)

Error lies in this line

```
var jsNode = new Alfresco.util.Node(model.widgets[i].options.nodeRef);
```

as Alfresco object is not available how can I get it?

Comment: Isn't the `Alfresco` JS object client-side only? The JS objects on the server side are different

Comment: This is used by all alfresco OOTB webscripts.The only difference is they have used it in supporting js file not in controller js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/share-extras-devel/XAVWkW3x070) yesterday on the [share-extras-devel](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/share-extras-devel) list:

Your issue is that you are mixing up your web script JS with client-side JavaScript. `Alfresco.util.Node` is a client-side helper class and is therefore available to client-side JS running in the web browser, but not to your web script code which runs on the server.

If you look at the source of `alfresco-util.js`, which you are including, you will see that there is a helper class there but it is called `AlfrescoUtil`.

To get some information on this given node I would suggest that you want to use the static method `AlfrescoUtil.getNodeDetails()` from that class, e.g.

```
var jsNode = AlfrescoUtil.getNodeDetails(model.widgets[i].options.nodeRef);
```

The structure of the `jsNode` object will be as per the JSON returned by the doclist-v2 webscripts, so you should be able to check for the presence of your custom aspect in the `aspects` array property.

If you check the source of `alfresco-util.js` you will see that additional parameters are also supported by `getNodeDetails()`. It seems to me you can also pass in an optional site name, plus some options if you wish.

Comment: thanks will for your clear explanation I understand my mistake actually this extension module is relatively new feature for me.I am looking in to this.